# Optimizing number of threads in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, io, data-processing

I am writing a program that analyses csv files in a directory, initially one file at a time. This could be several hundred files, but all of them are relatively small. My main runtime limitation was I/O, so I turned to multithreading using the threading library, which is a first for me.

I created a thread for each function call, following [this guide](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-threading/), where each function call opens a csv in the desired directory. As a result, I have a list of threads for each file (i.e. hundreds of threads). However, my program still ran slowly, with the bulk of its time spent `method 'acquire' of '_thread.lock' objects` according to cProfile. I believe that this is because of the large number of threads resulting in lots of threads waiting for others to finish their tasks - is this correct?

How would you recommend I resolve this? My current idea is to split my list of files into equally sized chunks and to assign a thread to each chunk, rather than a thread to each file, and for each thread to iterate through the files in each chunk.

Comment: Have you tried implementing your current idea of splitting the files into “chunks” or batches and assigning the work to fewer threads? Because of the explanation in my answer,  this approach should fix your problem if you use just a few threads instead of hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Python has something called the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://realpython.com/python-gil/)  which seriously hurts your performance with that many threads, as each one is waiting to hold the "interpreter lock." I would recommend using [Processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) which if I remember are similar to Python thread objects in their use but do not suffer the same performance penalty of waiting for a lock. A thread and a process *are* different, but for your application, it sounds like it should not matter.

It is worth noting that the GIL can be released when performing I/O such as reading from a file, and therefore using threads might be fine - you just need to use fewer of them. In fact, with the number of threads/processes you are looking to create it might be a better idea to use a [fixed pool of workers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers).